# visual studio 2008 - is it possible to split up code across two screens

Tags: .net, visual-studio

i have a dual monitor set up

i would like to see one part of Form1.cs on one screen, and the other on the other screen.

is it possible to have such a set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. VS 2010 offers that feature. Verra nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 doesn't support this. You could do it with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

In vs 2008 you can't do this. VS 2010 have this option. You can simply drag the window out and move it to the seocnd monitor